# API timeout in nginx but the same work in local server Django WSGI

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, nginx, wsgi

I am facing issue in my Django app...

which is working fine in mhy local django WSGI based server. but the same facing timeout in nginx..

what will be the issue?

is there anything to deal with increasing nginx process?

my nginx response which took **30000ms** to respond in my server but without data (i am using AWS),

[image]

my local got respond in **12000ms** with response,

[image]

any help?

My django app is on `AWS` i am using nginx gunicorn and supervisor for deployment configuration...

Comment: May be your setting file is different and forgot to add APP into setting file?

Comment: @Mohideen check your nginx configurations once. Nginx not passing the request to gunicorn process.

Comment: You may need to increase the timeout of gunicorn, the default is 30 seconds.
http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#timeout

Comment: i am having this alone, fail_timeout=0

Comment: Post your nginx config, logs and also see if you can find some debug info using http://tarunlalwani.com/post/how-to-debug-nginx-reverse-proxy-issues-php-fpm-gunicorn-uwsgi/

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend against fiddling with the Nginx and Gunicorn config.

Instead try reducing the amount of data you're trying to fetch in a single API response. If you're data is in the form of a list [which it looks like from the picture] I'd recommend paginating your response. Django has excellent pagination module which can be used.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/pagination/